# How to run Ruby file on Sublime Text

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I have a file named `add_and_power.rb` as below, and want to run it on Sublime Text.

```
def add_and_power a,b
  (a+b)**(a+b)
end

puts "First number please? "
input1 = gets

puts "Second number please? "
input2 = gets

puts "The result is: ", add_and_power(input1.to_i, input2.to_i)
```

I run `cmd+b`, but it just displays,

```
First number please? 
Second number please? 
The result is: 
1
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

I want to input `2` and `3` to get the answer. How can I make Sublime Text 2 ask for inputs and give back an answer?

Comment: It is not possible on *ST*.. Editors are not capable to run such code. Use `IRB` or *commandline*.

Comment: It is possible to do so using Sublime Text 2, it just isn't pretty.  Using the console that it opens up, and typing in there, to see program feedback in the editor.  Yech.  See my answer below.  But it is possible.  Use the REPL they give you or better yet, get comfortable with the terminal.

Comment: @Priti - it's perfectly possible in ST2, and in fact quite simple with the SublimeREPL plugin - see my answer below.

Comment: @MattDMo humm.. I just have seen. That's `PRY` tool. Still it is a `IRB` kind of thing. Anyway Nice :))

Comment: @Priti - it currently supports both `IRB` and `PRY`, and although there's a little "deprecated" note next to the `IRB` menu option it still works just fine...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run code within ST2, check out the [`SublimeREPL`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin, available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). You can either use `IRB` or [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry), which is a lot more powerful. You can use it as a classic REPL (think Clojure or LISP), and you can also transfer your code from one tab into the running REPL in another tab by selection, line range, or block.

In some of my tests the `pry` REPL doesn't handle input through `gets` very well, but I haven't played around with it that much. YMMV ***- Edit -*** As AGS mentions below, use `my_var = $stdin.gets` for interactive input within SublimeREPL Ruby.

I highly highly recommend SublimeREPL, as it's a really powerful tool, and is self-contained within ST2, so you don't have to keep flipping back and forth to your terminal, saving and reloading your programs.

Comment: Use `$stdin.gets` instead of `gets` in SublimeREPL Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run your programs when you need to have user input from the keyboard, but it isn't very nice.

When I do so, I need to input from a terminal that opens when I run Sublime, while also reading the response from the program at the bottom of the editor.

It is simply easier to run the program from the console/terminal.

So, the answer is, while it is possible to do so, there are concerns.  You may need to use `STDOUT.sync = true` or `STDOUT.flush` to help manage the buffer with the OS, you have two thing to look at, while doing so... yuck.

It may not be the answer you are looking for, but as a developer, you should be comfortable running things from the console/terminal.